# Split a list element in python by splitting by the '\t'

Tags: python

If i have a list element like the one below. How can i create a list with several elements by splitting by \t character?
`['county_id\temp_2010\temp_2020\temp_2030\temp_2040\thhld_2010\thhld_2020\thhld_2030\thhld_2040\tmf_2010\tmf_2020\tmf_2030\tmf_2040\tpop_2010\tpop_2020\tpop_2030\tpop_2040\tdu_2010\tdu_2020\tdu_2030\tdu_2040\tsf_2010\tsf_2020\tsf_2030\tsf_2040']`

Comment: Try: `my_list[0].split('\t')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> mylist = ['county_id\temp_2010\temp_2020\temp_2030\temp_2040\thhld_2010\thhld_2020\thhld_2030\thhld_2040\tmf_2010\tmf_2020\tmf_2030\tmf_2040\tpop_2010\tpop_2020\tpop_2030\tpop_2040\tdu_2010\tdu_2020\tdu_2030\tdu_2040\tsf_2010\tsf_2020\tsf_2030\tsf_2040']
>>> splitlist = mylist[0].split("\t")
>>> splitlist
['county_id', 'emp_2010', 'emp_2020', 'emp_2030', 'emp_2040', 'hhld_2010', 'hhld_2020', 'hhld_2030', 'hhld_2040', 'mf_2010', 'mf_2020', 'mf_2030', 'mf_2040', 'pop_2010', 'pop_2020', 'pop_2030', 'pop_2040', 'du_2010', 'du_2020', 'du_2030', 'du_2040', 'sf_2010', 'sf_2020', 'sf_2030', 'sf_2040']
```

should do the trick...

Comment: Yup this did it. I was trying something similar but i forgot to specify the [0] index of my list. Thanks

Comment: @PauloBu 22 seconds. An eternity on SO :)